# How can I create a pipeline between two jar files with the command prompt?

Tags: java, windows, command-line, jar, pipe

I'm currently stuck trying to run two jar files on a pipeline using the 
command line in windows 10.

=================================================================

These are the steps of what I typed into the console:

> 1.Execute: Adder.jar
>
> 5
>
> 7
>
> 2.Execute: Doubler.jar
>
> 4
>
> 3.Execute: Adder.jar | Doubler.jar (Pipe Adder's output into Doubler's input)

and this is exactly what I type into the console:

> C:>java -jar "Adder.jar"
>
> 5
>
> 7
>
> 12
>
> C:>java -jar "Doubler.jar"
>
> 4
>
> 8
>
> C:>java -jar "Adder.jar" | java -jar "Doubler.jar"
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>          at Adder.main(Adder.java:29)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>          at doubler.Doubler.main(Doubler.java:32)
>
> C:>

The null pointer exception at line 29 is from the Adder class's statement:

> String sFirstNumber = con.readLine();

And here's the main method from Adder class from 
which the jar file was created:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Console con = System.console();

 //      if (null == con)
 //      {
 //          System.out.println("!! Error accessing console: Run in
 //                                     a command window !!");
 //          return;
 //      }

    // Input two numbers from the input stream
    String sFirstNumber = con.readLine();
    String sSecondNumber = con.readLine();  
    int iFirstNumber = Integer.parseInt(sFirstNumber);;
    int iSecondNumber = Integer.parseInt(sSecondNumber);;   

    // Add the numbers
    int iTotal = iFirstNumber + iSecondNumber;

    // Output the result onto the output stream
    con.printf("%d", iTotal);
 }
```

When I run one jar file at a time everything works fine. It is until I try to connect the two jar files with the "|" command that 
the console throws the exception.

Before I commented out the if statement which checked if the console was null, The console would print out the message I wrote and terminate.

The console seems to run the jar file on a java virtual machine or something when I use the "|" command. Why else would System.console() be null when I use the "|" command with two jar files and not be null when I run one jar file at a time?

Answer (score 2):

The "|" command changes the standard input of your program.
Inside your Double.jar, the standard input would be the standard output of Adder.jar, which is not a console; this is why System.console() is null.

Just try using [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and System.out.println instead.

Comment: But isn't the Adder class throwing the exception aswell? If the input for the Doubler class is the output for the Adder class, why isn't the input for the Adder class the input from the console?